# Parallel Computing - Partial Sorting

Tags: sorting, parallel-processing

I have a number of parallel computing problems I am not sure how to do.

To conceptualize the problem, I'll give a real life example. I have a deck of cards (1-9) and I shuffle them. I draw 3 cards, and place the lowest on the table, then I draw another and place the lowest, etc.

I know how to do this serially, but I was wondering if there is a good way to do it in parallel. An example would be:

Problem:

8 2 5 3 9 7 6 1 4

Solution:

2 3 5 7 6 1 4 8 9

I've considered that each number can move forward twice, and back any number of times, but I still can't figure out a parallel method of doing this. Should I just run it all in serial off the first thread, or do it on the CPU?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

After considering this for awhile, I decided the fastest solution would be to iterate through each element and perform a swap if the next element was smaller, but to do a second set of swaps in parallel after the first set of swaps, such that it takes just over n+1 or +2 operations to achieve a double swap. Bigger hands could be supported at the cost of only a couple operations.